# Is there always a natural transformation from one function to another; and is it unique?

Tags: category-theory, functors, natural-transformations

Categories for the Working Mathematician says

> Given  two  functors  $S,  T: C \to B$,  a  natural  transformation  $r: S  \to\to  T$ 
>   is a function which assigns to each object $c$ of $C$ an arrow $\tau_c =  \tau c : Sc\to Tc$ 
>   of $B$  in  such  a  way  that  every  arrow  $f: c\to c'$ in  $C$  yields  a  diagram
>
> [image]

Given any two functors $S,T: C\to B$, is there always a natural transformation $r: S  \to\to  T$ ? Specifically, for each $c \in C$, is there always an arrow $Sc\to Tc$?

When there is, is such a natural transformation unique?  Specifically, for each $c \in C$, is such an arrow $Sc\to Tc$ unique?

Thanks.

Comment: No to both.  Not even close

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $I = 0\to 1$ be the category with two elements and a single non-identity arrow. Let $S: I \to I$ take both elements to 1, and let $T: I \to I$ take both elements to 0. Then there is no natural transformation $S\Rightarrow T$.

The answer to uniqueness is also no, I'll leave that as an exercise but I'd be happy to provide an example if you'd like.